# PrintWriter creates empty file

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I have the following problem I want to read a file and shift each letter down by 3 positions in the alphabet. The caesar cipher works correctly and I can print it, but whenever I am trying to pass it on to a new file with PrintWriter the file remains empty.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static char[] encrypt (int offset, char [] charArray) {
        char [] cryptArray = new char [charArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            int crypt = (charArray[i] + offset);
            cryptArray[i] = (char) (crypt);
        }
        return cryptArray;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "";
        StringBuilder convert = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            File file = new File ("C:\\PATH\\file.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner (file);

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                text = input.nextLine();
                convert = new StringBuilder (text);

                char [] arr = text.toCharArray();
                char [] newArr = encrypt(3, arr);

                for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
                    convert.append(newArr[i]).toString();
                }
            }
            input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        try {
            // write file
            File outFile = new File ("C:\\PATH\\newfile.txt");
            PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter (outFile);

            printer.print(convert);
            printer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't help you much but it works on my pc

Comment: Perhaps would it be something with eclipse then, if the code works fine for you ?

Comment: can your print `convert` before writing it into the file? using `System.out.print(convert)`

Comment: I launched it on ubuntu via eclipse. I find it strange you are not getting any errors. Did you try different paths?

Comment: It does only print if I put it inside the loop. Yes I already tried different paths aswell, my guess now would be that every char is not appended to the string correctly (see for loop).

Comment: Your code will only print the result of converting the last line of the file. If that line is empty you will get nothing. The printing should be done inside the read loop. And surely you should be using `println()`?

Comment: @user207421 I want to shift an entire text by 3 characters and the output should be written into a new file

Comment: So you shouldn't assign to `convert` inside the loop, only append to it.

Comment: Don't edit your post to remove the problem you're asking about. Ptherwise your question bcomes useless to further readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `convert = new StringBuilder (text);` in your loop. It's overwriting your data in the previous loop

Comment: This results in an infinite loop.

Comment: try to use the code you pasted above and remove that line instead of using the current version of code which we have no idea what changes were introduced

Comment: only remove the line I mentioned. Do not remove the line above it `text = input.nextLine();`

Comment: @Peon It does not result in an infinite loop. You changed something else. You can only get an infinite loop if the input is infinitely long or you aren't consuming it.

Comment: Thank you guys I now fixed it, I also had to remove .toString() when appending to the Stringbuilder otherwise the loop was infinite for me.

Comment: @Peon That's not true either. `String.toString()` just returns itself. It doesn't cause an infinite loop. Your infinite loop was caused by removing the call to `nextLine()`. Nothing else.